# how to open .clas file after adding extra code to actual java file

Tags: java

```
class Demo
{
int i;
}
```

After compiling this Demo.java file i get Demo.class file which is added by extra code that having defalut contructor

```
class Demo extend Object
{
Demo(Demo this)
{
super(this);
}
}
```

when i am going to open .class file using textpad and other editor tools it's showing some other fonts. But compiler is adding some extra code into java file.

So how to see that compiled file which having extracode like this.

Comment: You don't have to view a `.class` file in an editor. Usually you _run_ a class file, if it is runnable (has [`main()` method](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/main-program.html)). Please keep reading your Java textbook.

Comment: use a decompiler to open .class file. It will not open in textpad.

Comment: If you can't properly format your code, don't bother with decompiling classes. Start from the basics, not from the middle.

Comment: use java file to read your content.. If you want to open some class that provided by the jdk or any external jar lib you have added,then use jad decompiler..But for your own file, use java file no need to open .class file

Answer (score 0):

Use Java de-compiler to convert your class file to Java file again ..then you can see that 
how compiler takes your code .

You can use simple commandline decompiler JAD [JAD decompile download link](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class decompiler like jd-gui. It will decompile your class file.